# Ninject bind all factory interfaces

Tags: ninject, factory, ninject-extensions

Is there a simple way to use Ninject to bind all Factory interfaces to the ToFactory() extention method?

```
public class Foo
{
    readonly IBarFactory barFactory;

    public Foo(IBarFactory barFactory)
    {
        this.barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        var bar = this.barFactory.CreateBar();
        ...
    }
}

public interface IBarFactory
{
    Bar CreateBar();
}
```

For the code above I could use:

```
kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory();
```

What would I do though if I had 10 or 20 IFactory interfaces that needed binding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes use conventions: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions

```
this.Bind(x => x.From_UseSomeOverloadToSpecifyTheAssemblies()
                .SelectAllInterfaces().EndingWith("Factory")
                .BindToFactory();
```

Comment: I think I saw something like that before, but could never find the website again. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code out and I can not see anywhere how to pass a lambda to bind or even where SelectAllInterfaces() is. Conventions has a scan method which is the closest I can find, but it is still very different from your syntax.

Comment: The using statements I have are:   using Ninject;
  using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
  using Ninject.Modules;

Comment: Ok. It appears that I have an old version of the code. I looked at the code online and saw that it matches much better!